# Shooting a laser in 2d unity top down game

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I am trying to make my player shoot straight from his position to the direction I want and I did it, but now I have a cinemachine camre the I wanted it to stay in the larger background area so I added to the background collider and it worked for the camera boundaries BUT - now the laser I am shooting (which is dynamic) is colliding with the background and doesn't being shot.
I tried to make the laser bullet Kinematic but then its just instantiating and not being shot to distances.

So how can I make my laser bullet on dynamic and still not colliding with the background?

I tried the physics collision matrix without any success.

Also here is my shooting code:

```
public Transform shootingPoint;
public GameObject laserPrefab;
[SerializeField] float projectileSpeed = 10f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}

private void Shoot()
{
    GameObject laser = Instantiate(laserPrefab, shootingPoint.position, shootingPoint.rotation);
    Rigidbody2D rb = laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.AddForce(shootingPoint.up * projectileSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the background a different [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)

1. Select the Background and in the Inspector click on <kbd>Layer</kbd> → <kbd>Add Layer</kbd>

   [image]
2. Add a new Layer in an empty spot (doesn't matter which one exactly)

   [image]
3. Go back to the Background object and now select the new added layer

   [image]

Repeat this also for your **Player** and the **Laser** in order to be able to define exactly who should be able to collide with whom.

Then disable the collision between your laser (and other stuff) and the background via the [Physics2D Settings -> Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjjrL.png)
[image]

and make sure e.g. only the `Player` (or whatever needed) can collide with the Background

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I actually did that before and for some reason it didn't work but now it's just fine, thanks !